# Use ENUMS dynamically for option TAG in SELECT (REACTJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, html-select

I have ENUMS as listed below

```
export declare enum UserStatus {
    NEW = "NEW",
    REGISTERED = "REGISTERED"
}
```

How do i ensure that i can use this dynamic way as dropdown items of select tag. I searched online at several sites and didnt find a suitable answer. Can someone please help.

Currently i am hardcoding this way.

```
<select value={selectedUserStatus} onChange={onUserStatusSelect}>
      <option
        aria-selected="true"
        key={UserStatus.NEW}
        value={UserStatus.NEW}
      >
        {UserStatus.NEW}
      </option>
      <option
        aria-selected="true"
        key={UserStatus.REGISTERED}
        value={UserStatus.REGISTERED}
      >
        {UserStatus.REGISTERED}
      </option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's JSX syntax you should be able to replace the mark-up inside of the  element with an array of JSX elements like so:

```
<select value={selectedUserStatus} onChange={onUserStatusSelect}>
    Object.keys(UserStatus).map(key => (
        <option
            aria-selected="true"
            key={UserStatus[key]}
            value={UserStatus[key]}
        >
            {UserStatus[key]}
        </option>
        )
    )
</select>
```

Comment: Did this solution work for you? I typically use jsx in the context of Vue.js so I'm not totally sure this will work in React

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
<select value={selectedUserStatus} onChange={onUserStatusSelect}>
    Object.values(UserStatus).map(value =>
        <option
            aria-selected="true"
            key={value]}
            value={value}
        >
            {value}
        </option>
    )
</select>
```

Comment: I believe you need parentheses surrounding markup in JSX like that, or else you'll get a syntax error about a bad LHS argument.

Comment: No, in this particular case I do not

Comment: I'd recommend [validating your JS](https://validatejavascript.com/)